# How to append an array column to spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to duplicate data by a certain factor, below is how i do it with factor of `10`

```
val exploded_df = spark.sql("select * , explode(array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) as salted_key from  my_table ")
```

However, if I need to increase the factor of multiplication by 100 this process is not feasible.

wanted to do something like this but this won't work

```
val explode_factor = 20
val exploded_df = my_table.withColumn("salted_key", explode(List.range(0, explode_factor.toInt, 1).toArray))
```

Tried creating a `UDF` but no luck how do I achieve this by just changing `explode_factor`

Comment: could you please add your desired output table/dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using  `sequence` function (available since Spark 2.4)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sequence, explode, lit}

val explode_factor = 20
val exploded_df = my_table.withColumn("salted_key", explode(sequence(lit(0), lit(explode_factor), lit(1))))
```

Before Spark 2.4 you can do it as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, explode, lit}

val mySeq = List.range(0, explode_factor.toInt, 1).map(x=>lit(x))
val exploded_df = df.withColumn("salted_key", explode(array(mySeq:_*)))
```

Comment: I am aware of this but my server has only spark 2.3.1. Any idea to achieve this in `2.3.1`

Comment: @toofrellik I edited the answer and added solution for Spark version < 2.4